# How do I make Django admin URLs accessible to localhost only?

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, django-wsgi

What is the simplest way to make Django /admin/ urls accessible to localhost only?

Options I have thought of:

- Seperate the admin site out of the project (somehow) and run as a different virtual host (in Apache2)
- Use a proxy in front of the hosting (Apache2) web server
- Restrict the URL in Apache within WSGI somehow.

Is there a standard approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Id go for apache configuration:

```
<Location /admin>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for the Apache configuration + run a proxy in front + restrict in WSGI :

1. I dislike Apache for communicating with web clients when dynamic content generation is involved.  Because of it's execution model, a slow or disconnected client can tie up the Apache process.  If you have a proxy in front ( i prefer nginx, but even a vanilla apache will do ), the proxy will worry about the clients and Apache can focus on a new dynamic content request.
2. Depending on your Apache configuration, a process can also slurp a lot of memory and hold onto it until it hits MaxRequests.  If you have memory intensive code in /admin ( many people do ), you can end up with Apache processes that grab a lot more memory than they need.  If you split your Apache config into /admin and /!admin , you can tweak your apache settings to have a larger number of /!admin servers which require a smaller potential footprint.
3. I'm paranoid server setups.

   - I want to ensure the proxy only sends /admin to a certain Apache port.
   - I want to ensure that Apache only receives /admin on certain apache port, and that it came from the proxy (with a secret header) or from localhost.
   - I want to ensure that the WSGI is only running the /admin stuff based on certain server/client conditions.

Comment: A great answer - thanks! This is the cover-all-bases way to do it, I see.

Comment: Yeah, it's not much more work, and you get some peace of mind + server performance improvements. You can also still have it work differently on "dev vs staging vs production" via environment variables and deployment scripts.

Comment: You don't need separate Apache to split parts of the URL space across. You can handle that with mod_wsgi daemon mode by delegating different parts of URL namespace to different daemon process groups. You can then separately control number of processes/threads and automatic process restarts separately for a sub set of URLs by setting it for the specific daemon process group. Also, using a vanilla Apache as proxy in front still has many of same issues as direct facing Apache. Using nginx as proxy is still much better.